# Comparing undefined value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have an object whose value may be undefined sometimes. So is it possible / valid / good practice to test it with an if case like below :

```
if(params === undefined)  
{  
    alert("sound." + params);  
}
```

If not, why can't we do it?

As of now, it is working fine. Yet, I would like to know if it can go wrong anytime?

Thanks

Comment: As per my view, it will work everytime.

Comment: if you're specifically checking for `undefined`, that should be fine. by undefined, if you include an empty string, 0, null, etc. then that won't catch those.

Comment: Just to nit-pick, objects don't have a value, they have properties. What you mean is that you have a variable that may reference an object, or it might be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typeof varName` for safer usage:-

This will not throw any error if params is not a variable declared anywhere in your code.

```
 if(typeof params  === "undefined")
   {
       //it is not defined
   }

 if(params === undefined)   //<-- This will fail of you have not declared the variable 
        //param. with error "Uncaught ReferenceError: params is not defined "
 {
 }
```

#### [Refer Undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Nowadays (it is 2023), we are able to use such things like this: if ( params === undefined ) {  do something }. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#strict_equality_and_undefined

Answer (score 3):

Since in theory `undefined` can be redefined (at least pre-JS 1.8.5), it's better to use

```
if (typeof params === 'undefined')
```

This also works without throwing an error if `params` is not a known variable name.

Answer (score 1):

The *typeof* answers are good, here's a bit extra. To me, this is a case where you need to explain what you are doing with *params*. If you are doing say:

```
function foo(paramObject) {
  // determine if a suitable value for paramObject has been passed
}
```

then likely you should be testing whether *paramObject* is an object, not whether it has some value other than *undefined*. So you might do:

```
  if (typeof paramObject == 'object') {
    // paramObject is an object
  }
```

but you still don't know much about the object, it could be anything (including *null*). So generally you document the object that should be passed in and just do:

```
  if (paramObject) {
    // do stuff, assuming if the value is not falsey, paramObject is OK
  }
```

now if it throws an error, that's the caller's fault for not providing a suitable object.

The corollary is that all variables should be declared so that the test doesn't throw an error (and you don't need to use *typeof*, which is one of those half useful operators that promises much but doesn't deliver a lot).